# Why do all additive inverses of natural numbers precede $0_R$ in the integer ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, order-theory, integers

${\forall}a^{-1}:{\lnot}(a^{-1}\,{\in}\,\mathbb{N})\,{\land}\,(a^{-1}\,{\in}\,\mathbb{Z})\,{\land}\,({\exists}a\,{\in}\,\mathbb{N}:a*a^{-1}=a^{-1}*a=0):a^{-1}\,{\preceq}\,0$

How to prove the above?

Comment: Since you are being so formal, you are going to have to define what $a^{-1} \preceq 0$ means. I'm not sure that you are allowed to say $\forall a^{-1}$ either.

Comment: @StevenGregory Why am I not allowed to? It's just a variable symbol with three properies defined later narrowing down which elements of the set this theorem applies to. For $a^{-1}{\preceq}0$ I don't know why should I explain it, since $0$ and $preceq$ are widely used and recognized symbols.

Comment: Then how about $a \in \mathbb Z\setminus\mathbb N
   \implies (\exists {^-a}\in \mathbb N : (a+{^-a}={^-a}+a=0)
             \land (a \preceq 0)$ and I disagree that $``\preceq"$ is widely used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the axioms of an ordered ring like $\mathbb Z$ is:

> If $R$ is an ordered ring, and $a,b,c\in R$ and $a\leq b$, then $a+c\leq b+c$.

Given any negative integer $-z$, we can start with $0\leq z$ and then add $-z$ to both sides and invoke this axiom: 0+ (-z) $\le$ z+ (-z).